# rails default permission error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, security, permissions

i am setting up a cloud machine which comes with a default rails app. the app is accessible at `https://<hostname>:<port>/` ... When i enter this url i get the message

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server

The title of the page say **403 Forbidden**

I have little to no knowledge of rails but i do know that there might be a server file where the default permissions are set. Where is it and how can i fix it.

Comment: Could be that apache is not configured for external network requests (i.e. **httpd.conf**). This does not seem related to Ruby on Rails imo.

Comment: Can you give us an excerpt of apache's error log?